# Problem with kivyMD TCPModbus app not reading from the server

Tags: kivymd, modbus, modbus-tcp, scada, pymodbustcp

I created an app, based on a teacher's videoclass program. It turned out I had some issues, returning me the following exceptions and Id badly apreciate your attention:

```
Error during data status reading.
Error during data setpoint reading.
Error during data tempOven reading.
Error during data tempOven reading.
Error during data tempOven reading.
```

I know it's a theoric script, but I'd appreciate If u guys could run in your computers, because I hand-copied the teacher's scripts but It simply doesnt work althought it has no errors. As long as I post here the codes, Ill keep writting here its overviews and the files will be 3 (the kivyMD .kv, the main.py and the datacards). The app appearence is like that:[image: CONFIGURATION SCREEN]
The issues trigger exactly on the page below (data acquisition) because theonnection step is succesful.
[image: DATA SCREEN]

Starting with the main, this code instantiates the MDApp and sequentially the Screen. It has a button, as seen on the picture[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmDYn.png), for connecting. The connecting method himself instantiates the clock scheduler for eventual updates on the holding card and on the coil card.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from datacard import CardCoil, CardHoldingRegister, CardInputRegister
from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MyWidget(MDScreen):
    """
    Contructor
    """
    def __init__(self,tags,**kwargs):
        self._clientMOD= ModbusClient()
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._tags=tags 
        self._ev=[]   #pt4 min 58
        for tag in self._tags:
            if tag["type"]=="input":
                self.ids.modbus_data.add_widget(CardInputRegister(tag,self._clientMOD))
            elif tag["type"]== "holding":
                self.ids.modbus_data.add_widget(CardHoldingRegister(tag,self._clientMOD))
            elif tag["type"]=="coil":
                self.ids.modbus_data.add_widget(CardCoil(tag,self._clientMOD))
    
    def connect(self):
        if self.ids.bt_con.text== "CONNECT":
            try:
                self.ids.bt_con.text= "DISCONNECT"
                self._clientMOD.host= self.ids.hostname.text
                self._clientMOD.port = int(self.ids.port.text)
                self._clientMOD.open()
                Snackbar(text="Connected succesfully",bg_color=(0,1,0,1)).open()
                self._ev=[]
                for card in self.ids.modbus_data.children:
                    if card.tag['type'] == "holding" or card.tag['type']== "coil":
                        self._ev.append(Clock.schedule_once(card.update_card))
                    else:
                        self._ev.append(Clock.schedule_interval(card.update_card,1))
            except Exception as e:
                print("Erro de conexao com servidor: ", e.args)  
        else:
            self.ids.bt_con.text="CONNECT"
            for event in self._ev:
                event.cancel()
                self._clientMOD.close()
            Snackbar(text="Disconnected",bg_color=(1,0,0,1)).open()


class BasicApp(MDApp):

    
    __tags=  [{'name':'tempOven','description':'Oven Tempture','unit':'ºC','address':1000,'type':"input"},
              {'name':'setpoint','description':'Desired Tempture','unit':'ºC','address':2000,'type': "holding"},
              {'name':'status','description':'Actuator state','address':1000,'type':"coil"},

    ]
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette= "Orange"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue= "700"
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette="Orange"
         
        return MyWidget(self.__tags)

if __name__=='__main__':
    BasicApp().run()
```

The second file and next step is the datacard module. Its goal is to define 2 classes the MDcard one, and the 3 different MDcard children. Actually the 3 of them are repreenting the methodology differences between Mbus functions Holding, Input or Coil. Their goil is to interface with the server:

```
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard,MDCard
from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient

class DataCard(MDCard):             
    title= "Data Card"
    def __init__(self,tag,mbusClient,**kwargs):
        self.tag= tag                                          
        self.title=self.tag['description']          
        self._mbusclient = mbusClient
        super().__init__(**kwargs)  

    def update_card(self,dt):
        try:
            if self._mbusclient.is_open():
                self.set_data(self._read_data(self.tag['address'],1)[0])
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error during data",self.tag['name'] ,"reading.")

    def write_card(self):
        try:
            if self._mbusclient.is_open():
                self._write_data_fcn(self.tag['address'],self._get_data())
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error during data" ,self.tag['name'] ,"writting.")
    
class CardHoldingRegister(DataCard):
    def __init__(self,tag,mbusClient,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(tag,mbusClient,**kwargs)
        self._read_data=self._mbusclient.read_holding_registers
        self._write_data_fcn= self._mbusclient.write_single_register
    
    def set_data(self, data):
        self.ids.textfield.text= str(data)

    def get_data(self):
        return int(self.ids.textfield.text)
        

class CardInputRegister(DataCard):
    def __init__(self,tag,mbusClient,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(tag,mbusClient,**kwargs)
        self._read_data= self._mbusclient.read_input_registers
    
    def set_data(self, data):
        self.ids.label.text= str(data)
    

class CardCoil(DataCard):
    def __init__(self,tag,mbusClient,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(tag,mbusClient,**kwargs)
        self._read_data= self._mbusclient.read_coils
        self._write_data_fcn= self._mbusclient.write_single_coil

    
    def set_data(self, data):
        self.ids.switch.active= data    #True / False
    
    def get_data(self):
        return self.ids.switch.active                      #RETURN = ajuste
```

At last, we have the kivy .kv module, it diallogues with the datacrd module (e.g. when u want to show on the MDcard boxes the data exchanges between server and client) and with the main one (e.g connection and MD)

```
#:kivy 1.11.1
<MyWidget>:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "Informatica industrial"
        MDBottomNavigation:
            panel_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color
            text_color_normal:0.4,0.4,0.4,1
            text_color_active:0.8,0.8,0.8,1
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name:"config"
                text:"CONFIGURATION"
                icon: "cog"
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    padding: "20p"
                    spacing: "50dp"
                    Image:
                        source:"imgs/modbus.png"
                        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}   
                        size_hint: {1,0.2}    
                    MDTextField:
                        id:hostname
                        text:"127.0.0.1"
                        hint_text: "IP Address"
                        size_hint: {0.3, None}
                        height: "60dp"        #tentatativa e erro
                        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
                    MDTextField:
                        id:port
                        text:"502"
                        hint_text: "Port"
                        size_hint: {0.3, None}
                        height: "60dp"       
                        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.4}                        
                    MDRoundFlatIconButton:
                        id: bt_con
                        text:"CONNECT"
                        icon:'connection'
                        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.3} 
                        on_release: root.connect()
                   
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name:"data"
                text:"DADOS" 
                icon:"chart-donut"
                ScrollView:
                    size_hint: (1,None)
                    size: 800,600     #define o tamanho como o da janela 800x600
                    bar_pos_y: 'left'
                    bard_width: 20
                    effect_cls: 'ScrollEffect'
                    MDStackLayout:
                        id: modbus_data
                        size_hint: (1, None)
                        padding: 0.05*600,"150dp"
                        spacing: (800/5 - 2*0.05*800)/3
                        adaptive_height: True

<DataCard>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: '10dp'
    size_hint:None,None
    size: 600/5 , "90dp"
    pos_hint:{"center_x": 0.5, "center_y":0.5}
    MDLabel:
        text: root.title 
        size_hint_y: None
        height:self.texture_size[1]
        pos_hint: {'top':1} 
    MDSeparator:
        height: "1dp"

<CardHoldingRegister>:
    MDTextField:
        id:textfield
        helper_text: "Pressione Enter para enviar os dados"
        helper_text_mode:'persistent'
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: root.write_card

<CardInputRegister>:
    MDLabel:
        id:label

<CardCoil>:
    MDSwitch:
        id: switch
```

Im sorry if the question went too long, but that's it. If u prefer, I leave here the Youtube playlist which I'm basing on (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqO-KJXv6UE&list=PLDBnf2G73PkBqYVoxUoGQe7htYYE4fIsX&index=20). The teacher also shared the server module and It can be downloaded on the Youtube link above (on video descriptions). I appreciate any kind of tips and I thank u all beforehand.

Comment: Please try to provide a [**minimal**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I'd start by outputting the exception detail (e.g. `print("Error during data" ,self.tag['name'] ,"writting:", e)`) which should provide a starting point re tracing the issue.

Comment: hi man! Ty a lot for repliying, i did what u said but now i got  the following: Error during data status reading. ("'bool' object is not callable",)
Error during data setpoint reading. ("'bool' object is not callable",),  ... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://pymodbustcp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/package/class_ModbusClient.html#pyModbusTCP.client.ModbusClient.is_open) `ModbusClient.is_open` is a boolean (not a function). This means that attempting to use it as a function `if self._mbusclient.is_open()` will trigger the exception you are seeing.

To fix replace `if self._mbusclient.is_open()` with `if self._mbusclient.is_open` (i.e. remove the `()`. I'm not guaranteeing that is the only issue :-)...

Comment: TY Buddy! It really was the problem... Cya